# Table created in database but shows not created when I run the code

Tags: php

I made a php file to make my tables... and this is the code in all tables and stuff... now what happens is that it's creating table in database but... it shows table not created.
In rest of the codes it makes all the tables and shows :) I can't figure out what is wrong...

```
<?php
include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");

$tbl_users = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
               id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
               username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
               email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
               password VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
               gender ENUM ('m','f') NOT NULL,
               website VARCHAR(255) NULL,
               userlevel ENUM('a','b','c','d') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a',
               avatar VARCHAR (255) NULL,
               ip VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
               signup DATETIME NOT NULL,
               lastlogin DATETIME NOT NULL,
               notescheck DATETIME NOT NULL,
               activated ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
               PRIMARY KEY (id),
               UNIQUE KEY username (username,email)
              )";
$query - mysqli_query($db_conx, $tbl_users);
if ($query === TRUE) {
    echo "<h3>user table created OK :) </h3>";
}
    else {
        echo "<h3>user table NOT created  :( </h3>";
    }
}
```

Comment: `$query - mysqli_query($db_conx, $tbl_users);` Isn't that meant to be an `=`?

Comment: What ocracoke says is right, it should work after that, and you've got a } too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one to many curly braces in your if/else block and are not applying an assignment operator to your `$query` object, amend the code to:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $tbl_users);
if ($query === TRUE) {
    echo "<h3>user table created OK :) </h3>";
} else {
    echo "<h3>user table NOT created  :( </h3>";
}
```

And everything should work.